# change spring boot 2.0 context-path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to change context path for spring boot 2 for example i want to serve on http://localhost:8080/test/

i mean it not working for me with spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.0.0.RELEASE

it only working with spring-boot-starter-web::2.0.0.RELEASE

I have tried

```
server.servlet.context-path=/test
```

But nothing happened to me still serve on url http://localhost:8080/

Comment: `server.servlet.context-path` only works with embedded container. How are you deploying your application ?

Comment: it work with me on spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: but not working for spring-boot-starter-webflux

Comment: This is logical as webflux uses netty instead of a servlet container so I doubt properties in namespace `server.servlet.*` applies to `webflux`.

Answer (score 12):

If you use the servlet API then the property is now called

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myapp
```

Comment: This will work for the Spring MVC. It will NOT work for the WebFlux.

Comment: that's why I wrote "If you use the servlet API"

Comment: The original question is for Spring Boot 2.

Comment: @Gaurav then how we need to add for webflux ??

Comment: @prasannajoshi - If you are using Netty server with webflux, there is no concept of context-path. You can do manual routing on your controller endpoints.
But, if you want to use Tomcat server, you can do what is above and it will work.

Answer (score 7):

As confirmed by Andy Wilkinson [@andy-wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) of the Spring Boot team via Gitter

> There’s no concept of context path in WebFlux so there’s no equivalent property

i.e WebFlux doesn't support context path configuration

Comment: Spring Webflux itself does support contexts, but this feature is not supported in Spring Boot. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ContextPathCompositeHandler.html

Answer (score 6):

In spring boot 2.3.x you can set spring.webflux.base-path property

```
spring.webflux.base-path=/path
```

Answer (score 3):

In reference to Spring Boot 2.x. below configuration apply for application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /test
```

For application.properties configuration are

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path= /test
```

Comment: Your .yaml code didn't work for me, but application.properties worked great.

Answer (score 2):

For use cases where WebFlux application is behind load balancer/proxy you can use dedicated class - `ForwardedHeaderTransformer` that will extract path context from `X-Forwarded-Prefix` and will add it to `ServerHttpRequest`.

Doing so you won't need to modify global context-path (which does not make sense in WebFlux)

More about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-web-handler-api