# netty context path for spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I am using spring boot with webflux and removed embedded tomcat dependency from starter web , I wanted to add base context path for my application , is there any way i can do ?? I need this because i have ingrees properties behind kubernetes cluster and redirection is made based on context path.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Comment: You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196368/context-path-with-webflux)

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn , I tried the same before posting a question but no luck :(

Comment: Can you check this https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-web-handler-api

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot use spring web and spring webflux dependencies at the same time. If you do, spring will prioritize spring web and webflux filters will not be loaded at startup.**

During startup spring tries to create the correct ApplicationContext for you. As written here [Spring boot Web Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-web-environment) if Spring MVC (web) is on the classpath, it will prioritize this context.

**A spring boot application is either a traditional web application, OR it's a webflux application. It cannot be both.**

ContextPath is not something that is used in reactive programming so you have to filter each request and rewrite the path on each request.

This should work, its a component webfilter that intercepts every request and then adds the context path that you define in `application.properties`

```
@Component
public class ContextFilter implements WebFilter {

    private ServerProperties serverProperties;

    @Autowired
    public ContextFilter(ServerProperties serverProperties) {
        this.serverProperties = serverProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        final String contextPath = serverProperties.getServlet().getContextPath();
        final ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        if (!request.getURI().getPath().startsWith(contextPath)) {
            return chain.filter(
                    exchange.mutate()
                            .request(request.mutate()
                                            .contextPath(contextPath)
                                            .build())
                            .build());
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

But this will only work if your application is loaded as a Spring reactive application.

Comment: but I have created rest endpoints using Router functions and not by using the tradiational controller

Comment: read what i wrote. If you have spring mvc on your classpath, it will find it and load your application as non-webflux-application. It doesn't matter what code you have written or not.

Comment: why do you need spring web?